# How to accept multiple values into the same key parameter, as an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, parameters

After reading through quite a few threads here on SO as well as various book/web resources, I'm still at a loss for how to properly set up a parameter key so that it will take in multiple values on a single form.

The readme for strong_parameters seems to indicate this is possible by declaring the item in the params hash as an empty array, like this `params.permit(:id => [])`.

However, when I set up my params hash this way, it still manages to return only the last value for the key that was set in the form, rather than an array of all the values submitted by the user.

I notice too that the param key is showing to be a string, rather than an array. Running `params[:document][:key].class` returns String rather than Array. Also, when I experimented with including a `"name=key[]"` option in the form's text_field it complains of an undefined method 'merge' for "key[]":String.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I admit some of the controller code may be a bit rough, but at this point, I'm just trying to get the params hash to return an array of k/v pairs.  Thank you in advance for your help!

documents_controller.rb

```
before_action :get_key_array, only: [:create, :update]
before_action :get_value_array, only: [:create, :update]
before_action :combine_key_array_and_value_array_to_create_jsonb_object, only: [:create, :update]
before_action :save_jsonb_object_to_user_defined_attributes_field, only: [:create, :update]

...

private

  params.require(:document).permit(:key => [], :value => [])

# FIXME: Update to use push << ?
def get_key_array
  unless params[:document].nil?
    @key_array = [params[:document][:key]]
    # @key_array << params[:document][:key]
  end
end

def get_value_array
  unless params[:document].nil?
    @value_array = [params[:document][:value]]
    # @value_array << params[:document][:value]
  end
end

def combine_key_array_and_value_array_to_create_jsonb_object
  unless @document.nil? || @key_array.nil? || @value_array.nil?
    @jsonb_object = jsonb_object(@key_array, @value_array)
  end
end

def save_jsonb_object_to_user_defined_attributes_field
  params[:document][:user_defined_attributes] = @jsonb_object
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @document do |document_form| %>
  <%= document_form.label :key %>
  <%= document_form.text_field :key %>

  <%= document_form.label :value %>
  <%= document_form.text_field :value %>

  <%= document_form.label :key %>
  <%= document_form.text_field :key %>

  <%= document_form.label :value %>
  <%= document_form.text_field :value %>
<% end %>
```

After inputting test data like Key1, Value1, Key2, Value2, the params hash indicates that only the second set of input values are being added to the params hash

```
Parameters: { ..., "document"=>{"key"=>"key2", "value"=>"value2"}, "commit"=>"Create Document"}
```

UPDATE: If it matters, the :key and :value arrays are, themselves, not part of the document model. I used `attr_accessor :key, :value` to give the array values a "temporary" home to be used in the form and params hash, with the intention of transferring their values to the user_defined_attributes field, which **is** part of the document model. Just throwing this out there in case it's part of the issue.

Comment: Rails likes to have array parameters named like `key[]`, not `key`.

Comment: Thank you for your help again @mu_is_too_short! Can you elaborate a bit more where I'm misusing the param name?

Comment: In the form, set the fieldname to something like `key[]` - then rails will gather the various values of key into an array named `key` which you can then add to your params-method something like: `params.require(:key => [])`

Comment: What @TarynEast said. The underlying specifications allow parameters to be repeated regardless of what they're called but Rails requires parameter names to end in `[]` to indicate that they'll have multiple values (i.e. `x[]` means that parameter `x` will be an array in `param`).

Comment: @TarynEAst @mu_is_too_short Thank you! To clarify, when you talk about setting the fieldname, do you mean something like this? `<%= document_form.text_field :key, name="key[]" %>` Because whenever I do that, it returns undefined method 'merge' for "key[]":String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @TarynEast and @mu_is_too_short for their comments on this! You both are so kind with your time and StackOverflow is better for having you in its community! :) Thank you thank you!

Now, on to the solution...

Since I was setting up array variables (ie key and value) to temporarily store parameters that were not directly part of the Documents table, the solution was two-fold.

First I had to properly initialize these variables before using them in the controller.

At first, I experimented in document.rb with

```
def initialize 
  @key = Array.new
  @value = Array.new
end
```

but this threw some argument errors. I'm not sure why exactly, but I suspect Rails 5 frowns on the use of initialize since ActiveRecord uses it further up the chain to automatically set up attr_accessor methods...

So then I modified the array creation to use callbacks, and that did the trick!

**document.rb**

`after_initialize :create_key, :create_value`

```
def create_key
  @key = Array.new
end

def create_value
  @value = Array.new
end
```

Then, with the variables properly set up as arrays, the form now let me name the fields with array references (previously, it rightly complained about key and value being strings).

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= document_form.text_field :key, name: "key[]" %>
<%= document_form.text_field :value, name: "value[]" %>
```

Thoughts? Critiques? Improvements? I'm all ears and willing to learn :)